# Diff between two Thunderbird releases

Tags: diff, bugzilla, thunderbird

I discovered a bug in the newest stable release of Thunderbird. I reported it in Bugzilla, but nobody seems to investigate it. So I want to do such investigation myself.

I know the bug was not there in the previous version, which I think is TB 17.0.6 or so. And the bug appeared in version 24 (they changed the way of numbering, so these are really two consecutive versions).

Where can I get something like a diff between those versions? I'd prefer not to download the whole HG repo and do the diff myself. Is there an online service from Mozilla to do that?

I tried to start in Bugzilla: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/buglist.cgi?list_id=7970552&resolution=FIXED&query_format=advanced&bug_status=RESOLVED&bug_status=CLOSED&product=Thunderbird&target_milestone=Thunderbird%2024.0 . But it seems a great waste of time to me to browse all the fixed bugs and view their patches...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no online service for that. 
Even if you generate such a diff locally it's not something you could realistically read through as it would be absolutely huge, especially as there were a lot of tree-wide automatic changes to make the code more modern.

Comment: Thanks, I really used the local diff at last. The repo's not so large =) There's a little difficulty in that the HG repo doesn't have tags named e.g. "TB 24.0.0". But there are tags for aurora builds that have a date in their name, and those days are +- 1 day from the version release date. So I can navigate using those tags. Reading through the whole diff would absolutely be impossible, but having it you can at least grep for words you hope are causing the bug you're after :)